# How to make detection script , if detect old ie and redirect to another page?

Tags: php, html

How to make detection script , if  detect old ie and redirect to another page?

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way is probably to use [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I suggest wrapping them around a meta redirect. Other browsers will just see a HTML comment and ignore it. Example, this will redirect IE6 and lower to example.com:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
        <![endif]-->
     </head>
     <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get detailed information about the user agent using [get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) and then condition on the results of such a call to customize actions.

i.e.:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if($browser['version'] < 1.0){
    // redirect to `/newpage`
    header('Location: /newpage');
}
```