# How to show another page if client user use internet explorer?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Browser Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100898/browser-detection)
>   [How to make detection script , if detect old ie and redirect to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677511/how-to-make-detection-script-if-detect-old-ie-and-redirect-to-another-page)

I was wondering if is possible to show another page if the user is using internet explorer?

Is it possible in html? If I need php, please gimme some code.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish by detecting IE vs another browser?

Comment: Well, my website is not compatible with IE. Thats the reason.

Comment: Adrian really means why aren't you choosing to make it compatible with IE?

Comment: Becuse I Dont like IE, and cba to make it compatible with IE.

Answer (score 5):

Put this inside your HEAD tags.

```
 <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/"><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript, or methods library "JQuery", detect browser user-agent, load other page if IE. Be aware some browsers (like Firefox or Opera) might be masquerading as IE.